# Wicket LoadableDetachableModel exception handling issue

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5

In my project, I am using LoadableDetachableModel as given below.

```
public ReportPage(final Objectm, final PageReference pr) throws CustomException{
try{
final LoadableDetachableModel<List<MaintReport>> ldm = 
         new LoadableDetachableModel<List<MaintReport>>() {

            @Override
            protected List<MaintReport>load() {
                **// Some Database operations //** 
                return x;
            }
        };

/*
Several LoadableDetachableModels, PageableListViews, Panels, Fragments  etc.
*/ 
} catch ( Exception ex){
// create Custom Exception 
} finally {
 // Clean up of stuff 
}
```

The problem is that the overriding function **`load()`** invoolves some database operation. If an exception is thrown from this method or raised from this method, where can I catch ? . It seems I cannot catch. When I write some log messages, I see that the **`load()`** method is invoked after the entire contructor is executed.
I can definitely move the database operations outside the **`load()`** method. But is there any way to do so ?

If anyone has experienced this, It would be great if you could share the information.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how exception handling works. You need to do the exception handling inside the LDM. Wrap your *some database operations* in a try-catch statement.

Comment: Yea, I tried, but load() method cannot throw Exception out. The abstract class definition does not allow it to throw. But I want the entire Constructor to throw Exception out if the load methos fails.

Comment: You can throw any RuntimeException and register a RequestCycleListener that reacts on your exception.

Comment: So that means it is not possible to throw a checked Exception from this method. Yea,RuntimeException  and  using a RequestCycleListener  was my worst case plan. Anyways Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This code only defines the `load()` method and does not call it, so any exceptions it throws will not be caught in this try-catch.

The `load()` method in `LoadableDetachableModel` is normally called only be the `getObject()` method also defined in `LoadableDetachableModel` , which is called from other places in your application and the Wicket framework itself.

You should probably have a try-catch inside the `load()` method itself to handle any exceptions the database access might do.  If there is an exception you cannot handle within that method, you can throw a `WicketRuntimeException` wrapping the exception, which will normally lead to an error page.

Handling database errors outside that method will be painful.  Comments on the other answer give a hint as to how you could proceed.

Comment: Upon creating a new ReportPage by calling 'new ReportPage()', the 'load()' method gets called. However, when I look at the log files, it seems the 'load()' method is executed after the last line of code in the constructor. This is precisely the problem I have. I was trying to prevent the page from loading.  Knowing how the 'load()' method is triggered will give more understanding of handling errors efficiently.